# iOS Send JSON data in POST request using NSJSONSerialization

Tags: php, ios, json, post, nsjsonserialization

I know that there are similar questions posted as I have read though most all of them and still am having problems.  I am trying to send **JSON** data to my server, but I do not think the **JSON** data is being received.  I'm just not sure what I am missing.  Below is my code...

Method to send data to server.

```
- (void)saveTrackToCloud
{
    NSData *jsonData = [self.track jsonTrackDataForUploadingToCloud];  // Method shown below.
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", jsonString);  // To verify the jsonString.

    NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:http://www.myDomain.com/myscript.php] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60];
    [postRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [postRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [postRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [postRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [postRequest setHTTPBody:jsonData];

    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSError *requestError = nil;
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:postRequest returningResponse:&response error:&requestError];

    if (requestError == nil) {
        NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[returnData bytes] length:[returnData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"returnString: %@", returnString);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest error: %@", requestError);
    }
}
```

Method jsonTrackDataForUploadingToCloud

```
-(NSData *)jsonTrackDataForUploadingToCloud
{
    // NSDictionary for testing.
    NSDictionary *trackDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"firstValue", @"firstKey", @"secondValue", @"secondKey", @"thirdValue", @"thirdKey", nil];

    if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:trackDictionary]) {

        NSError *error;
        NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:trackDictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

        if (error == nil && jsonData != nil) {
            return jsonData;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error creating JSON data: %@", error);
            return nil;
        }

    } else {

        NSLog(@"trackDictionary is not a valid JSON object.");
        return nil;
    }
}
```

And here is my php.

```
<?php
    var_dump($_POST);
    exit;
?>
```

The output that I receive from `NSLog(@"returnString: %@", returnString);` is...

```
returnString: array(0) {
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your PHP, you're grabbing the `$_POST` variable, which is for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type (or other standard HTTP requests). If you're grabbing JSON, though, you should retrieve the raw data:

```
<?php

    // read the raw post data

    $handle = fopen("php://input", "rb");
    $raw_post_data = '';
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $raw_post_data .= fread($handle, 8192);
    }
    fclose($handle); 

    echo $raw_post_data;
?>
```

More likely, though, you want to take that JSON `$raw_post_data`, decode the JSON into an associative array (`$request`, in my example below), and then build an associative array `$response` on the basis of what was in the request, and then encode it as JSON and return it. I'll also set the `content-type` of the response to make it clear it's a JSON response. As a random example, see:

```
<?php

    // read the raw post data

    $handle = fopen("php://input", "rb");
    $raw_post_data = '';
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $raw_post_data .= fread($handle, 8192);
    }
    fclose($handle);

    // decode the JSON into an associative array

    $request = json_decode($raw_post_data, true);

    // you can now access the associative array, $request

    if ($request['firstKey'] == 'firstValue') {
        $response['success'] = true;
    } else {
        $response['success'] = false;
    }

    // I don't know what else you might want to do with `$request`, so I'll just throw
    // the whole request as a value in my response with the key of `request`:

    $response['request'] = $request;

    $raw_response = json_encode($response);

    // specify headers

    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    header("Content-Length: " . strlen($raw_response));

    // output response

    echo $raw_response;
?>
```

This isn't a terribly useful example (just checking to see if the value associated with `firstKey` was `'firstValue'`), but hopefully it illustrates the idea of how to parse the request and create the response.

A couple of other asides:

1. You might want to include the checking of the status code of the response (since from `NSURLConnection` perspective, some random server error, like 404 - page not found) will not be interpreted as an error, so check the response codes.

   You'd obviously probably want to use `NSJSONSerialization` to parse the response:

   ```
   [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:postRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
       if (error) {
           NSLog(@"NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest error = %@", error);
           return;
       }

       if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
           NSInteger statusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];
           if (statusCode != 200) {
               NSLog(@"Warning, status code of response was not 200, it was %d", statusCode);
           }
       }

       NSError *parseError;
       NSDictionary *returnDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];
       if (returnDictionary) {
           NSLog(@"returnDictionary = %@", returnDictionary);
       } else {
           NSLog(@"error parsing JSON response: %@", parseError);

           NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
           NSLog(@"returnString = %@", returnString);
       }
   }
   ```
2. I might suggest that you should use `sendAsynchronousRequest`, as shown above, rather than synchronous request, because you should never do synchronous requests from the main queue.
3. My example PHP is doing minimal checking of the `Content-type` of the request, etc. So you might want to do more robust error handling.

Comment: I will give this a try and let you know.  Although not shown in my code above, my NSURLConnection is not performed on the main thread.  The method `saveTrackToCloud` is called asynchronously.

Comment: Thank you!! I just tried out your php code and it fixed the problem! I had spent hours yesterday fighting this problem.  I figured it was probably my php code since my php skills are minimal.

Comment: @Rob is there a difference between using `$raw_post_data` vs `$_POST`?..I seem to have an issue using one over the other as explained in my question here if you can assist: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41423343/2373410

Comment: @Pangu - Yes, there's a difference. That's the main observation in this answer, namely that you cannot use `$_POST` for JSON requests. You have to capture the raw request and `json_decode` it.

Answer (score 0):

The [Advanced Rest Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) can be handy to test your web service. So, make sure that web service is acting as desired then map the same parameters in your client app.