# POST Request with JSON dictionary does not return correct value with $_POST in Swift 3?

Tags: php, swift, swift3

I'm trying to do is submit the device IMEI to be inserted into the database.

However, the returned JSON output from the database shows the IMEI as `null`.

Here's what's been implemented:

**Requester**

```
class Requester
{
    ....

    func postRequest(_ url: URL, headers : Dictionary<String,String>?, data: Data?, callback : @escaping (_ response: HTTPResponseWithData) -> Void) -> Void
    {
        let request = Factory.httpRequest(url, method: "POST", headers: headers, data: data)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
            data, response, error in

            print("RESPONSE: \(response)");

        })
        task.resume()
    }

    ....
}
```

**Factory**

```
class Factory
{
    func httpRequest(_ url: URL, method: String, headers:     Dictionary<String, String>?, data: Data?) -> URLRequest
    {
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = method

        if headers != nil
        {
            for (field, value) in headers!
            {
                request.addValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: field)
            }
        }

        if data != nil
        {
            request.httpBody = data
        }

        return request
    }
}
```

**MainVC**

```
let requester = Requester()

@IBAction func sendRequest(_ sender: Any)
{
    var json: Dictionary<String, Any> = [:]
    json["imei"] = myIMEI

    do
    {
        let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: .prettyPrinted)

        post(theData: data)
    }
    catch let error as NSError
    {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

func post(theData: Data) -> Void
{
    self.requester.postRequest("www.url.com", headers: nil, data: theData, callback: {(response: HTTPResponseWithData) -> Void in

        if response.statusCode == 200 && response.data != nil && HTTPHeader.isContentTypeJSON(response.mimeType)
        {
            print(response.data!)
            do
            {
                if let test = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions()) as? Dictionary<String, Any>
                {
                    print("test = \(test)")

                 }
            }
            catch
            {
                print("ERROR parsing data")
            }
        }
        else
        {

        }
    });
}
```

What I get back from the output is:

```
test = ["imei": <null>]
```

I've looked at numerous questions and answers on SO regarding this, and besides my implementation being in different classes, I don't see what could possibly be wrong.

Here's some snippet of the PHP code:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");

$imei = $_POST["imei"];
$something_else = $_POST["something_else"];

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $userid, $password, $database);

if ($mysqli->connect_errno)
{
    echo json_encode(array("success" => false, "message" => $mysqli->connect_error, "sqlerrno" => $mysqli->connect_errno));
    exit();
}

echo json_encode( array('imei'=>$imei) );
```

What exactly is wrong with my POST request implementation that is not allowing me to submit the IMEI to the database?

If it helps, the `RESPONSE` output is:

> RESPONSE: Optional( { URL:
>   http://www.url.com } { status code: 200, headers {
>       Connection = "Keep-Alive";
>       "Content-Type" = "application/json";
>       Date = "Mon, 02 Jan 2017 08:07:54 GMT";
>       "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=2, max=96";
>       Server = Apache;
>       "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity; } })

**UPDATE:** After further testing, I replaced the above php code after the `header` with the following code, and now the `imei` is reported:

```
$handle = fopen("php://input", "rb");
$raw_post_data = '';

while (!feof($handle))
{
    $raw_post_data .= fread($handle, 8192);
}
fclose($handle);

$request_data = json_decode($raw_post_data, true);
$imei = $request_data["imei"];
```

I'm confused, why is it the case that the updated php code works but the one involving `$_POST` does not?

Comment: In your postRequest in the Requester class your callback is never called. So don't you mean that your response is: "RESPONSE: json"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [`$_POST` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) which says it is:

> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP `POST` method when using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` as the HTTP `Content-Type` in the request.

But you're not doing `x-www-form-urlencoded` request. You're performing an `application/json` request. So you can't use `$_POST`. Use [`php://input`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) (e.g., as discussed here: [iOS Send JSON data in POST request using NSJSONSerialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188974/ios-send-json-data-in-post-request-using-nsjsonserialization/22190432#22190432)).